# Combining Dates and Ordering by Date

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, sql-order-by

I have the below Query

```
SELECT distinct 
COUNT(Status) AS [Transactions], 
left(DATENAME(mm, Date_Reported), 3) AS Month, 
DATENAME(yyyy, Date_Reported) AS Year

FROM [Transactions]

GROUP BY DATENAME(mm, Date_Reported), DATENAME(yyyy,Date_Reported)

ORDER BY Year, Month DESC;
```

My output is as below:

```
Transaction | Month | Year

123         | Jan   | 2000

1234        | Mar   | 2000

12          | Feb   | 2000
```

How can I alter the query so I can get the month and year together like "Jan 2000" and then order it by the date so Jan 2000, Feb 2000 and Mar 2000

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want :

```
SELECT COUNT(Status) AS [Transactions], t1.MonthYear
FROM [Transactions] t
CROSS APPLY ( VALUES (CONCAT(DATENAME(mm, Date_Reported),' ',
                             DATENAME(yyyy, Date_Reported)),
                      DATEPART(mm, Date_Reported)
                     )
            ) t1 (MonthYear, Morder)
GROUP BY t1.MonthYear, t1.Morder
ORDER BY t1.Morder;
```